# Analysis.. Norm on C([a,b])

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $w:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with $ w(x)\geq c>0 $ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $x \in  [a,b]$. Prove that

$$\lVert f\rVert_w \ = \ \displaystyle\int^b_a \lvert f(t)\rvert w(t)\ dt$$

is a norm on $C([a.b])$

I know generally how to check if a norm with the conditions but i really don't know what to do with this...

Comment: Of course, you need to assume that $w$ is well-behaved enough for all these integrals to actually exist.

Answer (score 2):

You have [3-4 properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) in the definition of the norm (depending on how they are grouped). Check all of them, one-by-one. Start with

- $\|f\|_w \geq 0$ for all $f$ and $\|f\|_w = 0$ if and only if $f \equiv 0$. Hint: in the latter case it is crucial that $w(x)\geq c$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and for some $c>0$.

Just as an example, 
$$
  \|\alpha f\|_w = \int_a^b|\alpha f(x)|w(x)\mathrm dx = \int_a^b|\alpha||f(x)|w(x)\mathrm dx = |\alpha|\int_a^b|f(x)|w(x)\mathrm dx = |\alpha|\|f\|_w.
$$

Comment: I have been struggling to show how this satisifes each of the four properties..

I understand the first... as $w(t)>0$ and as |f(t)| is strictly >0 so must the integral...

Then for f=0 then f(t)=0 and hence the integral will also =0..

But its the other conditions i don't really know how to prove..

Comment: @Mathsstudent147: well, you know that $|\alpha \cdot f(x)| = |\alpha|\cdot|f(x)|$ and $|f(x)+g(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)|$. And as Chris mentioned, it's better to assume that $w$ is e.g. continuous to assure the existence of all the integrals considered.

Comment: Im still really unsure how i use this to prove these last 2 conditions for this example.

Comment: @Mathsstudent147: edited to give an example

Comment: @Mathsstudent147 if the $w$ is well behaved (as usual for weights) all conditions are just properties of the Riemann integral.