# Prove that $\parallel f\parallel_w=\int_a^b\mid f(t)\mid w(t)dt$ is a norm on $C([a,b])$.

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

Let $w:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $w(x)\geq c>0$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and all $x \in [a,b]$.

Prove that $$\parallel f\parallel_w=\int_a^b\mid f(t)\mid w(t)dt$$ is a norm on $C([a,b])$.

Comment: actually if you take $\omega=1$ doesn't change the problem much.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310165/analysis-norm-on-ca-b).